# How do I load a docker multiarchitecture image in a machine with one of the architectures?

Tags: docker

Right now, I am looking into docker [multi-architecture builds](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-platform/), or what they are calling "multi-platform". However, it looks like the way this works assumes I am going to push the build to docker hub, then pull it from the machine with one of the sub architectures.

My current command builds the image for multiple architectures:

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64/v8 . -t yada:yada -f etc
```

But, when I output it to a tar:

```
docker save -o doesnt_work.tar
scp doesnt_work.tar myRemote:.
ssh myRemote "docker load -i doesnt_work.tar"
```

I receive a warning:

```
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
```

Although I expected some kind of docker magic to occur, I am happy to tell docker that the image is multi-platform with a `linux/arm64/v8` node. But, I don't see any way to do that in this `docker save` -> `docker load` command sequence.

Is there a way to `docker load` a multi-platform image on a device with an architecture different than the building device?

Comment: Is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72952846/165358) useful ?

Comment: @harrymc yep, I think I can figure it out from there